# Update MongoDB Driver for WebStorm plugin

Tags: mongodb, macos, driver, homebrew, webstorm

I'm trying to use the "Mongo Plugin" within WebStorm on OSX.  Two collections in my database are listing successfully within the IDE, but when I try to open other collections I receive error messages such as:

> org.bson.BsonSerializationException: Detected unknown BSON type "\x13" for fieldname "myfield.  Are you using the latest driver version?

The field generating this error message is the type BigDecimal, which is relatively new.  I've confirmed the path to my mongo shell is correct within the plugin at `/usr/local/bin/mongo`.

What should I do to update the driver?  I have researched this problem and know the location of the [MongoDB drivers](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/), but I have no idea which one to update for the plugin (or how).

Also, I verified any versions of Mongo through `homebrew` and `npm` are updated. These are probably not relevant.

NPM -g:

```
npm install -g mongodb
/usr/local/lib
└─┬ mongodb@2.2.22
  ├── es6-promise@3.2.1
  ├─┬ mongodb-core@2.1.7
  │ ├── bson@1.0.4
  │ └─┬ require_optional@1.0.0
  │   ├── resolve-from@2.0.0
  │   └── semver@5.3.0
  └─┬ readable-stream@2.1.5
    ├── buffer-shims@1.0.0
    ├── core-util-is@1.0.2
    ├── inherits@2.0.3
    ├── isarray@1.0.0
    ├── process-nextick-args@1.0.7
    ├── string_decoder@0.10.31
    └── util-deprecate@1.0.2
```

Brew:

```
brew install mongo
Warning: mongodb-3.4.2 already installed
```

Also the version of Mongo on the target server:

```
mongo --version
MongoDB shell version v3.4.1
git version: 5e103c4f5583e2566a45d740225dc250baacfbd7
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
allocator: tcmalloc
modules: none
build environment:
    distmod: debian71
    distarch: x86_64
    target_arch: x86_64
```

Comment: Try plugin author as well: https://github.com/dboissier/mongo4idea/issues

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the link provided by LazyOne, I discovered the plugin simply does not provide support for the Decimal type through [this issue](https://github.com/dboissier/mongo4idea/issues/184) as of this date.